# Can anyone explain to me how this code allows the stars to move?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to understand how this code works, can anyone explain it please.

```
def draw_star(star): # drawing a star
    # you only need to change a pixel, so use set_at, not draw.line
    screen.set_at((star[0], star[1]), (255, 255, 255))
    star[0] -= 1
    if star[0] < 0:
        star[0] = screen.get_width()
        star[1] = random.randint(0, screen.get_height())

stars = []
for i in range(1200):
    x = random.randint(0, screen.get_width())
    y = random.randint(0, screen.get_height())
    stars.append([x,y])

for star in stars:
    draw_star(star)
```

Comment: What's your best guess of what it does so far?  `screen.set_at` sets a position to be the RGB (255,255,255) which is white.

Comment: This code does not allow the stars to move. Maybe some essential code parts are missing. The stars are drawn only one time. Assuming that you use pygame this is only the initial setup of the stars. The main loop is missing. Isn't it?

Comment: `stars = [map(randrange, screen.get_size()) for _ in range(1200)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the code generates 1200 `[x, y]` coordinates, so each is a Python `list`:

```
stars = []
for i in range(1200):
    x = random.randint(0, screen.get_width())
    y = random.randint(0, screen.get_height())
    stars.append([x,y])
```

Each `x` and `y` coordinate consist of a random value within the constraints of the screen.

Next, each of these coordinates are drawn:

```
for star in stars:
    draw_star(star)
```

This passes the `[x, y]` coordinate list to the function `draw_star`

```
def draw_star(star): # drawing a star
```

This sets a white pixel at the given coordinates (`star[0]` is `x`, `star[1]` is the `y` coordinate):

```
    # you only need to change a pixel, so use set_at, not draw.line
    screen.set_at((star[0], star[1]), (255, 255, 255))
```

The code then subtracts 1 from the x coordinate (one step left). This changes the *original* list, because mutable lists are used:

```
    star[0] -= 1
```

If this changed the coordinates beyond the edge of the screen, the star coordinates are *replaced* with new coordinates on the right-hand side of the screen, at a random height:

```
    if star[0] < 0:
        star[0] = screen.get_width()
        star[1] = random.randint(0, screen.get_height())
```

If you were to *repeat* the `for star in stars: draw_star(star)` loop now with a screen blanking in between, you'd be *animating* the stars as moving from right to left, with new stars appearing on the right at random heights as stars drop off the left-hand side of the screen.

The core idea here is that the `draw_star()` function handles mutable lists and changes the values contained in them, effectively changing the contents of the global `stars` list for the next loop of the animation.